# how to navigate in unordered list tabs using keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using unordered list in this application. I want to create tab navigation using keyboard.What i need to create the tab navigation.The tab one contains a text boxes.after filling the text box. when user moves using keyboard into next tab it will go to next tab after pressing the tab key.
i am following this for creating a tabs: http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-tabs/

**This is my html list**

```
<ul class="tabNavigation">
        <li><a href="#first">tab-1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#second">tab-2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#third">tab-3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="first">First name:
        <input type="text" name="fname">
        <br>
        <br>Last name:
        <input type="text" name="lname">
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="second">City 1:
        <input type="text" name="city1">
        <br>
        <br>City 2:
        <input type="text" name="city2">
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="third">
        <p>tab 3</p>
    </div>
```

**This is my js**

```
$('ul.tabs').each(function(){
  // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
  // which tab is active and it's associated content
  var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

  // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
  // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
  $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
  $active.addClass('active');
  $content = $($active.attr('href'));

  // Hide the remaining content
  $links.not($active).each(function () {
    $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
  });

  // Bind the click event handler
  $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
    // Make the old tab inactive.
    $active.removeClass('active');
    $content.hide();

    // Update the variables with the new link and content
    $active = $(this);
    $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

    // Make the tab active.
    $active.addClass('active');
    $content.show();

    // Prevent the anchor's default click action
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, Key code of tab is 9. As a very small side remark, as your tabs are obviously ordered, it would be nicer to use an ordered list instead of an unordered one. But that's just to nitpick :-) (The same would be valid I guess for most of the navigation controls out there...)

Comment: Could you take a look at [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CQgYwsfrBJXUMoRPyL06?p=preview) and add your css?
I added the latest jQuery - do you need any specific version?

Comment: i am following this :http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-tabs/ for creating a tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add tabindex values, like this:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rVZ3f/1/)

```
<ul class="tabNavigation">
        <li><a href="#first" tabindex=1>tab-1</a>
        </li>
         <li><a href="#second" tabindex=2>tab-2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#third" tabindex=3>tab-3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="first">First name:
        <input type="text" name="fname" tabindex=4>
        <br>
        <br>Last name:
        <input type="text" name="lname" tabindex=5>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="second">City 1:
        <input type="text" name="city1" tabindex=6>
        <br>
        <br>City 2:
        <input type="text" name="city2" tabindex=7>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="third" tabindex=8>
        <p>tab 3</p>
    </div>
```

You can play around with the fiddle and change the tabindex values to see how it changes the order when navigating.

Comment: text box not come under the tab 1

Comment: http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-tabs/ i am following this tutorial. and waht i can write in script for tab navigation